# Using requestAnimationFrame more functional

Tags: javascript, jquery

I had to resort to the requestAnimationFrame function as the use of settimeout didn't work synchronously. (Due to slowing down or stopping on tab changes.)

However, to make requestAnimationFrame simpler to use (Taking the settimeout syntax as an example), I want to make something that I can use unlimitedly.

I currently have a code sample below.

However, as I said, I want to make it unlimited and flexible. There may be a mistake in the codes.

```js
let start = 0;
let delay = 1;
let num = 0;
function loop(timestamp)
{
    var delay_timestamp = delay*1000;
    if(timestamp - start > delay_timestamp)
    {
        start = timestamp;
        console.log(num++);
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}
loop();
```

**The style I want.**

I am aiming to make the requestAnimationFrame function more functional without using settimeout.

**I aim to make the requestAnimationFrame function more functional. By specifying how often each function will be called. For example, this could be a function called new_loop.**

```js
new_loop(function_name_1,1000);
new_loop(function_name_2,4000);
```

In summary, I want to make it more functional, as in the example above. Thank you for your help.

Comment: *as the use of settimeout didn't work synchronously.* Huh? `requestAnimationFrame` isn't synchronous either

Comment: @CertainPerformance I mean the slowdown in tab switching etc.

Comment: Do you mean that the throttling of inactive tabs is the problem, because it throws off your timing?

Comment: `However, to make requestAnimationFrame simpler to use (using the Settimeout example), I want to make something that I can use unlimitedly.` you can use requetAnimationFrame as often as you'd like

Comment: @Bravo Yes I know but I want to do this in a function that I can use indefinitely.

Comment: can you show some code that demonstrates what you want, even if it seems to make no sense,  because your words aren't making sense ... you keep referring to not using settimeout, and the settimeout example ... there's absolutely no settimeout in your code, so there is no settimeout example to help understand what it is you want

Comment: @Bravo I already have nothing to do with settimeout. I aim to make the requestAnimationFrame function more functional. By specifying how often each function will be called. Did you review the code that I specified as the style I want?

Comment: Ahh, the edit make it more apparent what you want

Comment: @Bravo I hope I explained. I'm waiting for your help. I'm asking and wondering about the code structure of the function called new_loop.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, you want to use requestAnimationFrame to "power" a setTimeout-like function

I believe the following is what you want

```js
const animationTimeout = (cb, ms, ...args) => {
    const go = start => {
        const anim = now => {
            if (start + ms <= now) {
                return cb(...args);
            }
            af = requestAnimationFrame(anim);
        }
        af = requestAnimationFrame(anim);
    }
    let af = requestAnimationFrame(go);
    return {
        cancel: () => cancelAnimationFrame(af)
    }
};
console.time('test');
animationTimeout(() => console.timeEnd('test'), 2000);

// this one will be cancelled before it triggers
const x = animationTimeout(() => console.log('you will never see this'), 2000)
setTimeout(() => x.cancel(), 1000);
```

and for interval

```js
const animationInterval = (cb, ms, ...args) => {
    const go = start => {
        const anim = now => {
            if (start + ms <= now) {
                cb(...args);
                start = now;
            }
            af = requestAnimationFrame(anim);
        }
        af = requestAnimationFrame(anim);
    }
    let af = requestAnimationFrame(go);
    return {
        cancel: () => cancelAnimationFrame(af)
    }
};
const interval = animationInterval(() => console.log(new Date), 1000);
setTimeout(() => interval.cancel(), 5500);
```

The only thing the above does NOT have is a way to cancel the timeout/interval - but thats pretty easy to add

edit: added cancelling

Comment: How can I use the function to be called here? I have not seen an example of this. How can I run a function called write every 2 seconds with the method you wrote? That's what I meant by using unlimited. I want to run a function called read every 4 seconds using the function you made on another line?

Comment: erm ... it's just like using setTimeout .... I even have an example in the snippet ... isn't that what you wanted? a setTimeout-like funciton that uses animation frame?

Comment: In other words ... in your question, where you use `new_loop` - that would be this answers `animationInterval` if it runs every n milliseconds, OR, this answers `animationTimeout` if it runs once after n milliseconds - sorry I didn't make my function names as un-descriptive as you wanted

Comment: How can I get console.log(new Date) to call a function called write() instead. Could you add an example where a function is called instead of a console.log?

Comment: do you know how to use setTimeout/setInterval? that's how - a function IS called `() => console.log('xxx')` IS a function - do arrow functions confuse you?

Comment: ok ... so you know how in your question you have `new_loop(function_name_1,1000);` .... replace `new_loop` with `animationInterval` ... tada - done - or, copy my answers code, and instead of calling the function `animationInterval` call it `new_loop` ... tada - done - no rocket surgery required

Comment: @perfectmorn - I probably did not understand what you want - seems the code I posted has done more to confuse you than help you - maybe you should explain more about what you want (in your question)

Comment: const interval = animationInterval(() => write(), 1000); When I use it like this, will the write function be executed?

Comment: your question has no such code, so how the heck should I know @perfectmorn  ... how about you do `new_loop(function_name_1,1000);` like in your question - except use my better name `animationInterval` (or `animationTimeout` - whichever is appropriate to your requirements)

Comment: I think you didn't read the question twice. What did I say? "I aim to make the requestAnimationFrame function more functional. By specifying how often each function will be called. For example, this could be a function called new_loop." Your code seems to partially handle this. The only difference is that it runs the function name I wrote.

Comment: huh? I read the question ... looks like you want something that works like setInterval, but uses requestAnimationFrame ... that's what `animationInterval` does ... exactly - I originally thought you wanted a setTimeout replacement, since all you did was talk about setTimeout, never setInterval ... you know the difference, right? One triggers once, the other multiple times? Anyway ... I probably don't understand what you want becaue your question doesn't actually describe what you want